How to get Xcode to create an .xcframework rather than a .framework?
If you create new project from Xcode (v16) and choose framework, and then build it, it results in a .framework.
How do you instead get it to build an .xcframework?
When creating the framework project there's no options presented to create one or the other.

An xcframework is an archive of frameworks with different architectures. You should create the framework first and then create the xcframework. An xcframework is somewhat like a fat framework.
First, create frameworks for each architecture. Then, create the xcframework by:
    xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
    -framework yourAppSimulator.framework \
    -framework yourAppIOS.framework \
    -output yourApp.xcframework


